# While loop not re-opening import document after initial request

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, while-loop

```
def add():
    import add_coffee_record

def show():
    import show_coffee_records

def search():
    import search_coffee_records

def modify():
    import modify_coffee_records

def delete():
    import delete_coffee_record

def main():
    num=input('\nEnter the number on the menu: ')
    while num != '6':
        if num == '1':
            print()
            add()
        if num == '2':
            print()
            show()
        if num == '3':
            print()
            search()
        if num == '4':
            print()
            modify()
        if num == '5':
            print()
            delete()
        num=input('\nEnter the number on the menu: ')

main()
```

When I run the FIRST input, it calls the function and the import file just fine. But when I make another request, it just asks me again for my input. It just loops that forever. I want it so that if I ask it to show my coffees 10 times, it shows them 10 times in the output. Not this "one time and it shuts down" nonsense. Anybody helping would be greatly appreciated. Here is a sample messed up output:

```
Enter the number on the menu: 2

Description: Thanksgiving Blend
Quantity: 300.0
Description: Christmas Blend
Quantity: 100.0
Description: French Blend
Quantity: 200.0
Description: Espresso
Quantity: 600.0

Enter the number on the menu: 2


Enter the number on the menu: 2


Enter the number on the menu:
```

Comment: One question. Why import something over and over again? Why not import it just once, assuming it has methods/functions in it, why not call them to display the output instead?

Comment: This is what my assignment requests from me. The "super-menu" that I'm creating should allow one to, say, add a coffee and then view the list. And then add another coffee and view that new list until the user kicks out with '6'. Does that make sense? We cannot have a giant overbloated program with 6 different programs inside one.

Answer (score 2):

You're abusing `import`; it isn't meant to be used this way. Instead, take the contents of `add_coffee_record.py` and place them in your function definition:

```
def add():
    # contents of add_coffee_record.py go here
```

And do the same for your other functions. Alternatively, define the functions in the other modules and import them once at the top of your script.

At a high level, when you write `import mymodule`, Python executes the module and stores all of the new objects -- variables, functions, classes, etc. -- in something like a dictionary. When you re-import the module, Python doesn't need to re-execute the module, as it already has all of the things it defines in the module dictionary. This is what you're seeing: the second time around, Python just uses the cached module.

You can test this by creating one module:

```
# hello.py
print("Hello! I'm in a module!")
```

and importing it twice from another:

```
# test.py
print('First import:')
import hello

print('Second import:')
import hello
```

You'll see:

```
First import:
Hello! I'm in a module!
Second import:
```

Comment: Our assignment explicitly prevents us from making a giant program like that. Is there a way around it within the while loop? Thanks!

Comment: So how do I ask python to use the cached module on the second, third, fourth, etc. times around? Thanks!

Comment: "Alternatively, define the functions in the other modules and import them once at the top of your script." I don't understand that...can you elaborate? thanks!

Comment: That would hardly classify as a "giant program". There are other questions on this site which will help you with defining a function in another module and importing it.

Comment: My professor called it a giant program and disbarred it as a right method. Sorry.